# Drupal 8 - Block module as a webservice

Tags: php, web-services, rest, drupal, drupal-8

i want to use a webservice with drupal 8 that returns a block module <=> Module as a webservice that can be used by another module or another website

Is it possible ? How can i do it ?

Drupal version: 8.2.4

PHP version: 5.6.11

Comment: Could you provide more details? like what exactly do you return(html, xml/json data, etc), how you want to access that, etc. Ofcourse is possible, everything is possible. Also what do you mean by "block module", my mind is at block but i miss the "module" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using Block-render module https://www.drupal.org/project/block_render